# How to make File Upload Control a conditionally required field?

Tags: infopath, file

I have four optional buttons. The file or amortization is required to be uploaded only if either `Loan` (One of the four option buttons) is selected or `Bond` is selected.
Another words user must upload amortization for both `Loan` and `Bond` options.

I cannot use submit button rules, as this form can be submitted without the file attachment if one of the other two remaining option buttons is selected.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Conditional Validation

Select the FileUpload control and choose Rules -> New Validation

Under Condition -> Click None and Add the two conditions which validates whether `Loan` is selected or `Bond` is selected.

http://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/